# SwiftUI Preview Core Data with Relationships

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, preview

I'm trying to work with Core Data & SwiftUI's previews and think I'm close but haven't been able to get this to work.

```
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newGame = Game.init(context: context)
        newGame.gameName = "Testy Game"
        newGame.gameDescription = "Wooo play the thing"
        newGame.goal = Goal.init(goalName: "Try Harder", goalComplete: false, goalOfGame: newGame)
        return GameGoalsDetail(game: newGame).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

I'm getting a "Ambiguous reference to member 'init(entity:insertInto:)'" on the newGame.Goal = Goal.init... line.

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a new Game and then initialize a connected Goal to it right after.

My Core Data Game class takes gameName, gameDescription, and a goal as a NSSet?.
The Core Data Goal class has goalName, goalComplete, & goalOfGame: Game?. I think my issue is in connecting the two.

Appreciate the help in advance and willing to share more code if requested.

Comment: Is the Goal init method yours? How does the Goal get a reference to the MOC?

Comment: what is Goal? How do you initialize it with no context? All the `@NSManagedObject` have defined `init` with context. In with context will `Goal` be inserted?
By the way, you don't have to use `.init()`. Just call `Game(context: context)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Goal` is `@NSManagedObject` thats why you need to use its init with context. When tou create an entity object, you must place it in some store - context is that store. After that you can cast all the properties you need including links.

```
let goal = Goal(context: context)
goal.goalName = "Try Harder"
goal.goalComplete = false
goal.goalOfGame = newGame
return GameGoalsDetail(game: newGame).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

if you set reversed links in data model, there is no need to use add-methods generated by CoreData, if you have at least 1 `one-to-one` link. You just set this link as a property value and CoreData do all the work for you. `goal.goalOfGame` is that property - reverced link `one-to-one` to it parent.

If you realy want to use init with all the property you want to cast, just override it in extention to your class like this:

```
extention Goal{
    init(of game: Game, name: String = "unnamed", complete: Bool = false, context: NSManagedObjectContext  
    ){
        super.init(context: context)
        self.goalOfGame = game
        self.goalName  = name
        self.complete = goalComplete 
    }
}
```

Comment: added some ditails

Comment: In other tries I was so close. Just needed the goal.goalOfGame = newGame. I was using so many variations but kept missing that one.

Answer (score 2):

If they are one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, you can't simply assign the Goal to the Game. When you use core data with relationships you get free "add" methods with the name of your relationship. You should be creating the Goal on one line

```
let newGoal = Goal.init(goalName: "Try Harder", goalComplete: false)
```

and then add the newGoal by calling:

```SwiftUI
newGame.addToGoal(newGoal)
```

That should take care of any inverse relationship as well.

Comment: I think it not necessary. I use one-to-many and it works with no add-method called. i just fill child-entities reversed-link property (it is one-to-many) and that's it. This item automatic inserts to parent `@NSManaged` `NSSet`.